# about update data on datagridview and filter

Tags: sql, vb.net, datagridview, dataset, dataview

i'm getting confuse about dataset and dataview, which i either use dataset to update data or dataview to filter data, but cannot have both together at the same time.

```
Private Sub searchStaff_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

        ds = New DataSet

        dv = New DataView

        Dim ad As New SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM staff", connection)

        ad.Fill(ds, "staff")

        dv.Table = ds.Tables("staff")

        Me.DataGridView1.DataSource = dv
End Sub

Private Sub txtSearch_TextChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles txtSearch.TextChanged

         Try
                dv.RowFilter = "StaffName like '" & txtSearch.Text & "*'"

          Catch ex As Exception
        End Try
      End Sub
```

this is the code of filtering data on dataview,which work fine for me.
but later on, i have to implement another function of update data on datagridview, what i found on internet require me to use dataset as datasource rather than dataview.

```
Private Sub searchStaff_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

        connection = New SqlConnection(connectionString)
        ds = New DataSet
        cmd = New SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM staff", connection)
        adp=New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
        adp.Fill(ds, "staff")
        Me.DataGridView1.DataSource = ds
        Me.DataGridView1.DataMember = "staff"

    End Sub
Private Sub btnUpdate_ClickEvent(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnUpdate.ClickEvent
    Dim cmdbuilder As New SqlCommandBuilder(adp)
    Dim i As Integer

    Try
        i = adp.Update(ds, "staff")
        MsgBox("Record updated= " & i)

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub
```

so i hope some 1 can show me, how to i can have both functions"update,filter" at the same time by using what datasource?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must use DataSet (or DataTable) with SqlDataAdapter for make an Update operation; DataView is used for filter data but not to commit changes to database. Here an example for your searchStaff_Load method:

```
Private Sub searchStaff_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load         

    connection = New SqlConnection(connectionString)    
    ds = New DataSet         
    cmd = New SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM staff", connection)    
    adp=New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)        
    adp.Fill(ds, "staff")
    Me.DataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables("staff").DefaultView 'Assign DataView to grid
    'Me.DataGridView1.DataMember = "staff"      'No need when using DataView

End Sub
```

The txtSearch_TextChanged and btnUpdate_ClickEvent are already correct. The first filter using DataView, the second update database using DataSet.